# centering a div inside a div

Tags: css, html

page I'm working with: http://jsbin.com/abewe4

I want the `slogan` div centered inside `col3` div

I'm using

```
width: 50%; 
margin: auto;
```

on the inner div but still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.slogan {
color:#143063;
font-size:18px;
**line-height:92px;** //Add this line without the asterisks(*)
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Samwick a you should accept this as the answer then. You have a 60% accept ratio. Not horrible, but...

Comment: I'm getting better mate. at the time of the comment I tried to accept the answer but jeff's logic said I still had to wait X minutes. So I went and took the trash out

Answer (score 2):

You need to add ‘text-align: center‘ to col3.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    .col3{
        display:table-cell;
        width:200px;height:200px;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:middle;
        border:1px solid blue;
    }

    .col3 .slogan{
        border:1px solid red;width:100px;height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
</style>

<div class="col3">
    <div class="slogan">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can give any height or width to **col3** or **slogan** the css will make it center align always

You can put any element inside slogan and it will be center aligned :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a div called `col3` and a nested div classed `slogan`. Here is how I would do it.

```
#col3 {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}
.slogan {
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   text-align: left;
}
```

`slogan` should have a fixed width for the margin: 0px auto to center it.